# How to sort list of names by date and get last in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, tags

I'm retrieving the list of artifacts from arifactory:

```
https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/storage/TEST-REPO/com/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/app-dist-1.0.1-20161206.093508-1-bin.zip
https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/storage/TEST-REPO/com/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/app-dist-1.0.1-20161206.125420-2-bin.zip 
...
```

How can i compare this list by date and take the latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
sort -t- -nk5 list.txt | tail -1
```

Separate by character '-' and sort by the 5th column (which has the date), then print only the last line of the output.

Check if it works properly just in case of I haven't taken into account some date format which may appear in your file.